# Is there any criterion for deciding the kernel size of convolutional layer and pooling layer?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In this picture: 
[image: enter link description here]
<sub>(source: [ele.tue.nl](http://parse.ele.tue.nl/cluster/2/CNNArchitecture.jpg))</sub>

the input is 32x32, the `C1` is 28x28 and the kernel size of  `"Convolutional"` layer and pooling layer is 5x5 and 2x2 respectively.
But why 5x5 not other number, that is, how we decide the kernel size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While asking why `kernel_size` is 5, why don't you ask why the `num_output` (number of hidden neurons) is 4?

Kernel size, like the number of layers, number of hidden variables when and what pooling method to choose are all part of the design choices of a neural net. Picking up these values is part of the "dark art" of designing new architectures and it usually involves trail-and-error and lengthy training process.

As a rule of thumb, the larger the kernel, the slower the train/test time of your net. On the other hand, large kernels enables you to learn more complex templates thus enable the net to have stronger expressive power. It's up to you to decide where you want to be on this run-time vs. expressive power with your model.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Actually I also want to how to decide the num_output but I saw some questions about this topic before.The answer of these questions shows num_output  is a parameter one can tune.Best way to determine the number of feature maps is to try different values and check the accuracy.Do you have some better ideas about it?

Comment: @ZhaoWulanaren if you find a better way, please let me know ASAP -- tuning these "architecture parameters" is a very tricky "dark art"...

Comment: @ Shai Sorry, I might have to trouble you again.I have a new question about tset result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737309/how-to-evaluate-the-result-is-good-or-not-in-caffe