# How to evaluate the result is good or not in caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I train my data set using caffe. I set (in `slover.prototxt`):

```
test_iter: 1000
test interval: 1000
max_iter: 450000
base_lr: 0.0001
lr_policy: "step"
step_size: 100000
```

The test accuracy is around 0.02 and test loss is around 1.6 at the first test. Then the test accuracy increase and the test loss decrease every test.
At iter 32000 the test accuracy is 1 and the test loss is 0.45.
Then the accuracy decrease and the loss increase.
I think the loss is too large when accuracy is 1. 
How do I know the result I got is good or not?
Is there any method I can use to make an evaluation?

Comment: what is your test set size? what is `batch_size` for test?

Comment: train set size 516068;train batch_size is 256 ;test set size is 103212;test batch_size is 50

Comment: You need to set `test_iter` to 2065 (~ 103212/50) to cover the entire test set at each test iteration.

Comment: what does the train loss looks like at iteration 32000?

Comment: The train loss is same as test loss at iteration 32000

Comment: It takes you about 2000 iterations to go over all your training examples (516068/256) that is 1epoch ~ 2000 iterations. By the 32000th iterations you completed about 16 epochs and it seems like you are starting to oferfit your training set. Does the training loss keeps decreasing after the 32000th iteration?

Comment: One strange thing is that my train loss always decrease after test output until 220 iteration and  it change to a large number abruptly and then decrease until the next test output.

Comment: After 32000th iteration, train loss  decrease after test output until 220 iteration and it change to 1.26 abruptly and then decrease until the next test output

Comment: Uploading the output log will help us better understand the problem

Comment: OK,but where can I find it?

Comment: I meant, show us all the output prints that happen during your training

Comment: OK,but it may need some time.Because I don't save it. I need to run the programma again.